# SpringBoot app not use application.properties from a personal library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, application.properties

I create :

- one library using Spring (common-spring)
- one springboot project which use this library.

In my library common-spring, I have create multiple `HealthIndicator` (Actuator).

In my HealhIndicator I define the `@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator`

```
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("mailServiceIndicator")
@Component
public class MailServiceHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator
```

I would like to indicate that all these Indicator are disabled by default.
So, I add in my library application.properties :

> management.health.mailServiceIndicator.enabled=false

My problem is : this properties is not take account when I run my springboot application.
It's seem that the application.properties of my library is not use.

I try to change the name of my libray `application.properties` to `common-spring.properties` and add in a `@Configuration` class :

```
@PropertySource({
        "classpath:common-spring.properties",
        "classpath:application.properties"
})
```

But that no change the behavior.
(When I do that and I read the propertySource, properties from library are well found but not use in my Indicator in the library)

If I was clear, does anyone have any idea how to get my libraria to use the `application.properties`?

Thanks

Comment: Only one `application.properties` will be read, the one that is first on the classpath (which will always be the on in the application **not** the one in your. Using `@PropertySource` won't work as that hasn't been processed when doing the `@Conditional` checks. Instead of specifing defaults in your file, hardcode them in your condition (if properry not available assume `false` else use value from property). No need to mess around with an additional file etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Ok but how do you do to put a value false if property is not know in the : ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator ?

Comment: You don't you just return `false` for the `Condition`.